# How to reference a request in multiple Collections

Tags: postman

I'm new to unit testing so perhaps the following isn't ideal, but here is what I would like to do.

Is it possible to create a set of requests that are referenced by multiple collections? Also for each collection, I would like to set environment variables to be used by each request to dynamically change the request's values. For a basic CRUD API I would like to have a Collection that has valid input to test successful creations. I would also like a Collection that uses invalid input to test for failed creations. I would also like to do the same for read, update, and delete operations. In addition, I would like to be able to have a collection that exercises all operations and to verify each step along the way.

In the cases above, each CRUD request has the same headers, authorization, json payload structure, etc. The only thing that is different is the values of the json. I'm trying to avoid copying each request for each collection because if the request needs to change then I would have to modify it N times which would be a pain.

I know Postman recently introduced Workflows, but it seems too difficult to try and control different test scenarios from the perspective of the request. To me, it seems ideal that each collection would model a specific test scenario.

Answer (score 2):

My question is really multiple questions, but at its core it was really about trying to apply dynamic variables to a collection to test different scenarios. I recently found that Postman has supported this since 2014. In the Collection Runner you can provide a data file which has data variables that are applied to each request. Essentially the data variables are read from the file and are applied as environment/global variables so your requests will need to be updated to do this. The data file can be in CSV or JSON and allows you to define which data variables you need and then specify for each request their values. This Postman [blog](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/) provides more in depth information.